# How to use Custom Font whose file size is higher than asset folder in android?

Tags: android

I would like to use custom font in my application,
so i just put that font file in asset folder. The file size is 4mb but the asset folder size is 2mb, so my font is not working..

This is my code

```
 final TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
 textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,
    new FastBitmapDrawable(info.getIcon(mIconCache)), null, null);
 Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/chen.ttf");
 textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
 textView.setText(info.title);
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "you know the asset size is 2m,my font is 4m."?

Comment: the asset size default size is only 2m,my font size is 4m,so my font not used

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of talking about this limit, and it is supposed to have be removed by Android 2.3. Howevever, for preivous versions, a few tricks are available. The problem is file compression preformed by the system when your apk is built.

An easy but not so clean workaround is to change the file extension of your font file to one that is not compressed. For instance,  call your file chen.mp3. This way, you  are not limited.

Further reading and more details about this :

[Dealing with asset compression](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/)
[Using asset resource or raw ressource](http://www.41post.com/3985/programming/android-loading-files-from-the-assets-and-raw-folders)

Hope this helps.